# Add lang-js syntax formatting hint for [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Google Apps Script is a JavaScript variant, and it would be appropriate to default to lang-js for the 14k+ questions tagged [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

In the mean time, savvy users can insert the formatting hint in a comment:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

...and I imagine the less savvy will continue to add [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) just to get the formatting.

Comment: Pretty(print) please?

Comment: Well, I had completely forgotten about your question (and that I upvoted it) by now...

Comment: Hopefully the additional tags get some attention on this! (not holding my breath...)

Comment: For my understanding: is this not something you can manage once you hit 2500 rubber chicken pulleys?

Comment: @Gimby: Missing the point a little bit...

Comment: @Gimby We definitely don't want a synonym for that, for the same reason we don't want a synonym `node.js` -> `javascript`: The syntax may be the same, but the environment/API is not.

Comment: @TinyGiant I keep missing the point if all I'm told is I'm missing the point :( So apparently management of language highlighting and managing synonyms are completely different editing actions.

Comment: @Gimby - I didn't understand your initial comment, but now I think I do. That's right - syntax highlighting and tag synonyms are different topics. While making the tags synonyms may make syntax highlighting work, it has undesired side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done.

Questions like [Google apps script 6 minute execution time limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306357/google-apps-script-6-minute-execution-time-limit) now look slightly more colourful!